# Alt/Win key behavior in ubuntu gnome 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome

It seems that "Alt/Win key behavior" option is no longer available in gnome settings. how can I change my super key to control?
my 2nd question is that how to change the shortcut for rename from F2 to Enter? (already changed the ~/.config/nautilus/accels but it didnt work)

Answer (score 3):

It's been removed from Ubuntu 14.04, but luckily you can go ahead and do this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

And then open the Application "Tweak Tools" -> "Typing" and there you go

I don't yet know the answer to your second question.